# login to tryton and problem with the host

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, psql, tryton

I am beginner with tryton so excuse my question.

which host and profile should i use .

I need to connect to the server but i don't know which what host do i need.

I tried to log in whith localhost:8000 and local and localhost and ip address but all of these trials failed.

So is there a problem with the installation of tryton or am i entering the wrong host and profile.

```
INFO:tryton.rpc:common.server.version(None, None)
ERROR:tryton.rpc:[Errno -2] Name or service not known
exit
INFO:tryton.rpc:common.db.list()
INFO:tryton.rpc:common.server.version(None, None)
INFO:tryton.rpc:common.db.list()
INFO:tryton.rpc:common.server.version(None, None)
ERROR:tryton.rpc:[Errno -2] Name or service not known
gnuhealth@ghealth:~ $ exit
déconnexion
[otbs@ghealth ~]$ tryton
ERROR:tryton.rpc:[Errno 111] Connexion refusée
ERROR:tryton.rpc:[Errno 111] Connexion refusée
ERROR:tryton.rpc:Remote end closed connection without response
```

here's a photo below.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you test that the trytond server is running on your machine?

Comment: if you mean trytond --verbose then i guess it soesn't work , otherwise howa can i verify the server?